# Angular8: получить начальный URL с аргументами

Tags: url, angular

Angular 8
Хочу открывать страницу с передачей начального параметра в URL, например:

https://mysite.com/param_init

где и как поймать этот параметр (param_init), до перехода на страницу логина

Comment: У вас в примере, вроде, не параметр, но часть пути. Параметр должен так выглядеть: `http://domain.zone/path?param=value`.

Comment: С этим вопросов нет, где его прочитать в приложении, при открытии страницы?

Answer (score 0):

Входящие параметры можно считать так:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, ParamMap} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParamMap
        .subscribe(paramMap => console.log('param value: %s', .get('param')));
  }
}
```

В итоге, при открытии компонента по ссылке, к которой будет добавлен параметр с именем `param` в консоль выведется его значение.

---

Если же надо части пути получить, то можно так:

```
this.route.url.subscribe(value => console.log('path parts: ' + value));
```

Например, для запроса `http://localhost:4200/#/article/129` выведет

> path parts: article,129

Comment: Я наверное не точно поставил вопрос. Мне надо прочитать параметр, содержащийся в пути, по которому открывается сайт. Между компонентами я читаю так: const id = this.activeRoute.snapshot.params.id;

Comment: @VasilyAsur, если я правильно понял - то смотрите дополнение к ответу

Comment: в каком компоненте это делать?

Comment: @VasilyAsur, ну, наверное в основном... Или в любом. Я не знаю что у вас в коде, сложно сказать. Может у вас нет навигации через `#` и код из ответа работать не будет или потребует некоторого изменения.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, еще нашел здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997369/how-to-get-param-from-url-in-angular-4

Comment: @VasilyAsur, если вы нашли решение своей проблемы - напишите об этом в ответе, если в моём ответе решения нет. Ну или исправьте мой ответ, если тут что-то не так)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрел здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997369/how-to-get-param-from-url-in-angular-4

у меня код выглядит так:

в AppRoutingModule добавил строку с "prm/:id":

```
const routes: Routes = [
     { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
     { path: 'prm/:id', component: LoginComponent },
     { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
```

в LoginComponent добавил в ngOnInit:

```
 this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(paramsId => {
           const id = paramsId.id;
           console.log(id);
         });
```

Путь выглядит так:
http://localhost:4200/prm/3213515

Пока все получается